# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max_results' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

```
for _ in range(10):
    try:
         next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['next_results']
    except KeyError or e:
        break
    kwargs = dict([ kv.split('=')
                    for kv in next_results[1:].split("&") ])

    search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(**kwargs)
    statuses += search_results['statuses']
    if len(statuses) > max_results:
        break

q = "CrossFit"

results = twitter_search(twitter_api, q, max_results=10)

print (json.dumps(statuses[0], indent=1))
```

Comment: more context please, full stack trace? full code?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

The code posted is not what you ran, as `search_results` is not defined and execution would stop there.  My guess, based on what you posted, is that `max_results` is not defined when `len(statuses) > max_results` is executed.  In your original code, the loop must be within a function definition.  The error message can only occur when a name within a function, defined to be local because it is an assignment target, is used before any assignment.  For instance:

```
>>> def f():
    if True: return y
    else: y = 1

>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    f()
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 2, in f
    if True: return y
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
```

Please read and act on this SO [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help page.  What you posted is both incomplete and over-complete (everything after the if statement is superfluous).